# Can you add a 3D model viewer to website hosted on Github without users being able to download the model?

Tags: html, github, 3d

So I want to add a 3D model viewer to my website that's being hosted on github using this script: https://github.com/google/model-viewer, but I don't want people to be able to just download the models. Is there a way to somehow restrict that or no?

The only solution I can think of is to not host the site on github but then I wouldn't be asking this question-

Comment: If any portion of that model is needed in the browser to view it then the model must be downloaded.